# Generate dummy sql rows based on value

Tags: sql, oracle

Now I have a table "Fruits" with the following data

```
ID  Fruit  Users
===============
1   Apple  5
2   Orange 4
3   Banana 3
```

I want to query the data with generated dummy rows(or duplicated records) depended on the value of the users

```
Fruit  Users
===========
Apple  5
Apple  5
Apple  5
Apple  5
Apple  5
Orange 4
Orange 4
Orange 4
Orange 4
Banana 3
Banana 3
Banana 3
```

I tried to join the table but it does not work since the number of the rows is fixed.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you want to do this? Ideally you should handle this in a different way. Like use `Users` value to loop through some data set.

Comment: You are right but the instruction is I have to generate the corresponding rows in the excel document. I know I could do this with VBA but I would try it in sql since it would be more flexible if I face the similar problem again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with a (idx) as (
         select level from dual connect by level <= (select max(users) from fruits)),
     b as (select fruit, users, idx from fruits join a on idx <= users)
select fruit, users from b order by users desc,  fruit
```